# Are these the type of API that I can use to communicate with my college's Moodle from my app?

Tags: android, moodle

if so. how? I dont understand how they can be used

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the web services API is what you need and is also how the official Moodle app communicates.

See: http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services